# Perfect Secrecy for Shift Cipher

Tags: encryption, perfect-secrecy

I've read the definition of **perfect secrecy** as the following:

*A cryptosystem has perfect secrecy if $\Pr(x | y) = \Pr(x)$, for all $x \in P$ and $y \in C$, where $P,C$ are respectively the set of plaintexts and ciphertexts*.

Now suppose there are 26 keys in the Shift Cipher (**SC**) with probability 1/26. Then for any plaintext with probability distribution, SC has perfect secrecy.

The proof starts with:

$$\Pr(y)  = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}_{26}} \Pr(k)\Pr\left(x = d_k(y)\right)$$

I didn't comprehend this part (the probability distr. on $C$), and the way it's calculated.

*obs.: the encryption rule for shift cipher is $e_k(x) = (x+k) \text{ mod 26} (x \in \mathbb{Z_{26}})$*.

*Also note that $K$ is the set of keys.*

Comment: Any $c = x + k$, so probability of selecting $k$ times probability of there is $x$  decryption of $y$ under the key. In this case, second is always 1. And sum all.

Comment: Why second is always 1?

Comment: For every plaintext there is always a ciphertext under any key, and the reverse is also true.

Comment: Now, I can comprehend.

Comment: When ready, you can write your own answer, this way you can learn more. Our community will check your asnwer...

Comment: Are you sure that this SC has the original SC or a modified one that only accepts one character to encrypt? [Can a shift cipher attain perfect secrecy?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/5662/18298)

Comment: I don't comprehend well what you mean.

Comment: If you read the answer properly you need to see that; Shift Cipher (SC) can only attain perfect secrecy if it is restricted to one letter encryption. So one needs to mention this; let $SC'$ be the modified $SC$ such that for a random key it only encrypts one character. In the end, this is what One-Time-Pad if you continue to use another random key per character.

Comment: Did you notice the point?

Answer (score 2):

We will prove that $\Pr[x |y] = \Pr[x]$, first notice that, since, for each element of $P$, we always have an element of $C$, under a key, $\Pr\left(x = d_k(y)\right) = 1$, so:

$$\Pr(y)  = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}_{26}} \Pr(k)\Pr\left(x = d_k(y)\right) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}_{26}} \Pr(k) $$

Now, the sum stands for the union of all associations of one key and a decryption.

But, since $e_k(x) = (x+ K)  = y \mod 26$, we conclude that $\Pr\left(x = d_k(y)\right) = \Pr (y-K) = 1$. It's clear that $\Pr(k) = 1/26$, so $\Pr(y) = 1/26$.

Now, $\Pr[y|x] = \Pr[K] = 1/26$, because given $x$, $y$ is unique (uniquely determined via the $K$). Now by **Bayes' Theorem** we know:

$$\Pr[x|y] = \frac{\Pr[x]\Pr[y|x]}{\Pr[y]} = \frac{\Pr[x]\cdot 1/26}{1/26} = \Pr[x]$$

and this concludes the fact that **Shift Cipher** brings Perfect Secrecy.